# Unable to Upload the File into DropBox From Salesforce Using /Files_put API?

Tags: salesforce, dropbox-api, apex-code

I tried to upload the file into Drop Box account From `Salesforce` Using `/files_put Dropbox Api`. But am always getting following Error :

> [Status=Bad Request, StatusCode=400]{"error": "Body may not be empty"}.

Hereby My Code as follows,

```
public class DropboxController
{
public Blob FileBody{get;set;}
public DropboxController()
{

}
public PageReference DropAuth()
{

HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setMethod('POST');
request.setTimeout(60000);   request.setEndpoint('https://apicontent.dropbox.com/1/files_put/auto/Test.txt');
Blob val = csvFileBody;
Blob accesstoken = Blob.valueOf('<redacted>');
String AccToken = 'Bearer ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(accesstoken);
request.setHeader('Authorization', AccToken);
request.setBodyAsBlob(val);
System.debug(val);
Http hp = new Http();
HttpResponse response = hp.send(request);
System.debug(' RESP ::: ' +response +''+ response.getBody());
return null;
}
}
```

Please advise .
Thanks,
Vivek.K

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205549593-Unable-to-Upload-the-File-into-DropBox-From-Salesforce-Using-Files-put-API- ]

Comment: Hi All, i got the solution.Am unable to share full code here.for reference link - > https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000ssnWQAQ